Fill in null values with last non null value
I'm attempting to create a list of dates, IDs, and a StatusCodes. I'm trying to replace null StatusCodes with the most previous StatusCode.
Table A is a list of all Ids
Table B is a list of all date values between two dates defined
Table C is a list of all Ids with StatusCode changes and the date of those StatusCode changes.
I'm trying to use First_Value and Last_Value with no luck.
Current



Date
Id
Status




1/1/24
1
null


1/2/24
1
1


1/3/24
1
null


1/4/24
1
2


1/1/24
2
1


1/2/24
2
null


1/3/24
2
null


1/4/24
2
2



Desired



Date
Id
Status




1/1/24
1
null


1/2/24
1
1


1/3/24
1
1


1/4/24
1
2


1/1/24
2
1


1/2/24
2
1


1/3/24
2
1


1/4/24
2
2



My Code is the following:
declare @dt table ([Date] date)
DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2022-09-10'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = '2022-09-30'

/* below creates temptable of dates between timespan defined above */
WHILE ( @dIncr <= @dEnd )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @dt VALUES( @dIncr )
    SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr ) 
END
/* above creates table of dates between timespan defined above */

select
*
,LAST_VALUE(c.StatusCode) over (partition by a.Id order by c.IdDate) as Attempt1
,case 
    when c.StatusCode is null then First_Value(c.StatusCode) over (partition by a.Id order by   
        a.Id rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) 
    else c.StatusCode 
    end as Attempt2
,case 
    when c.StatusCode is null then LAST_VALUE(c.StatusCode) over (partition by a.Id order by 
        b.date)
    else c.StatusCode 
    end as Attempt3
    
from (
    select 
    distinct Id
    from OnlyIdsTable
) a

cross join 
    (
    select * from @dt
    ) b

left join 
    (
    select IdDate,Id,StatusCode from DatesAndIdStatusChangeTable
    ) c
    on 
    a.Id= c.Id
    and b.[Date] = c.adjdate

order by a.Id,b.Date asc



FIRST_VALUE/LAST_VALUE & LEAD/LAG would only help you on 2022+, as they support IGNORE NULLS, but you're on 2019.

He can add order by case when col is not null then 0 else 1 end... ahead of his condition, this will make them work?

See example (https://dbfiddle.uk/s84a3uYY) Or, more strict, (https://dbfiddle.uk/pVedgTnP)
